# Gradually store increment number in array? - calculate avg rollover

Tags: php, mysql, average, increment

(For easy understanding I think the easiest way to look at it is with jackpot rollovers)
I have this data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5ea89/1/0

I got the current/latest jackpot rollover by checking previous wih current row in the result as seen here and then increment $rollovercount:

```
$rollovercount = 0;
$previous = '';
$stmt = DB::Prepare("
        SELECT jvt.jackpotvalue, jt.dateofjackpot
        FROM JackpotTable jt
        LEFT JOIN JackpotValueTable jvt on jvt.jackpotid = jt.jackpotid
        ORDER BY jt.dateofjackpot desc
        ");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result)
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $current = $row->jackpot;

        if ($current < $previous) 
        {
            $rollovercount ++;
        }
        $previous = $current;
    }
 }
 return $rollovercount ;
```

This works well but now I would like to get the average rollover count.
If you see the example data the latest rollover count is 3(the jackpotvalue went down from previous row).
Before that it was 5 rollovers.
Before that it was 2 rollovers.
Before that it was 1 rollovers.
Before that it was 2 rollovers.

So 3+5+2+1+2=13 and 13/5=2.6 so 2.6 is the average amount of rollovers.

Maybe if somehow it's possible to store the rollovers in an array like $rollovercount = array(3, 5, 2, 1, 2); and then maybe use array_sum($rollovercount) and divide that with count($rollovercount)

Comment: When a rollover occurs, add the current rollover count to the array, and reset `$rollovercount` to 0.

Comment: Yeah but how would I do this in code - acutally putting the current rollover count into the array and then move on and check next rollover count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$rollovercount = 0;
$rolloverCountArray = array();
$previous = '';

$stmt = DB::Prepare("
    SELECT jvt.jackpotvalue, jt.dateofjackpot
    FROM JackpotTable jt
    LEFT JOIN JackpotValueTable jvt on jvt.jackpotid = jt.jackpotid
    ORDER BY jt.dateofjackpot desc
    ");
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result)
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $current = $row->jackpot;

        if ($current < $previous) 
        {
            $rollovercount ++;
        } else {
            $rolloverCountArray[] = $rollovercount;
            $rollovercount = 0;
        }
        $previous = $current;
    }
}
return array(
    "rollovercountLast" => $rollovercount,
    "rolloverCountAvg"  => array_sum($rolloverCountArray) / count($rolloverCountArray)
);
```

I haven't tested this code, but I hope it will give you an idea how to approach this problem in code. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks hade to make some adjustments: if ($current >= $previous) and:
(array_sum($rolloverCountArray)+$rollovercount) / (count($rolloverCountArray)+1) since the array wouldn't contain the "latest/first" count